# Acceder a JSON por indice en php

Tags: php, json

Estoy tratando de acceder a un json mediante índice. La estructura del json es esta:

```
{
"type":"champion",
"format":"standAloneComplex",
"version":"10.25.1",
"data":{
   "Aatrox":{
      "version":"10.25.1",
      "id":"Aatrox",
      "key":"266",
      "name":"Aatrox",
      "partype":"Blood Well"
   },
   "Ahri":{
      "version":"10.25.1",
      "id":"Ahri",
      "key":"103",
      "name":"Ahri",
      "partype":"Mana"
   },
   "Akali":{
      "version":"10.25.1",
      "id":"Akali",
      "key":"84",
      "name":"Akali",
      "partype":"Energy"
   } 
}
}
```

Lo que quiero hacer es recorrer los objetos de "data" para en cada uno de ellos buscar su
"key" para comprobar que me coincida con una variable, y en caso de ser asi obtener todos los atributos de dicho objeto. Ejemplo: Tengo la "key" 103 y de ahi buscar en el json y obtener el "id", el "name" y el "paratype", de en este caso "Ahri".

De esta forma me devuelve correctamente lo que hay en data

```
$championData = json_decode(file_get_contents("./media/other/champion.json"))->{"data"};
```

Por lo que lo siguiente que probe fue:

```
$championData = json_decode(file_get_contents("./media/other/champion.json"))->{"data"}->{"Aatrox"};
```

De esta forma tambien me devuelve los datos esperados, pero necesitaba en lugar de indicar"Aatrox", poder indicar un numero para recorrerlo con un for y salir de dicho for en caso de encontrar lo necesitado.

También intente con: (suponiendo que 0 seria el indice)

```
 $championData = json_decode(file_get_contents("./media/other/champion.json"))->{"data"}->{0};
```

Esto ultimo no me devolvía nada. Lo ultimo que intente fue:

```
$championData = json_decode(file_get_contents("./media/other/champion.json"))->{"data"}[0];
```

Lo que me devolvia el siguiente error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No vas a poder acceder con `[0]` porque no es un array con índices numéricos, son diferentes objetos cada cual con sus atributos. Para recorrerlo con un bucle como mencionas, usa un bucle [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php) y podrás recorrerlo facilmente tal que así:

```
/* Primero que nada, no hace falta usar los {} ni las comillas para acceder
 a los atributos de un objeto, basta con poner el nombre después de la flecha*/
$championData = json_decode($data)->data;

/* Ahora recorreré el array de campeones uno a uno, almacenándolos en la variable $hero
en cada iteración del bucle. Es decir, primero $hero tendrá a Aatrox, luego a Ahri...*/
foreach($championData as $hero){
    // Aquí dentro basta con usar $hero->nombreAtributo para acceder a ellos, simple!
    if($hero->id == "Aatrox"){
        echo "Encontrado Aatrox";
        // Si solo buscas un héroe en concreto, un break te evita iteraciones innecesarias
        break;
    }
}
```

Espero que el ejemplo te sirva, he omitido la parte donde lees el json porque obviamente no tengo acceso al archivo para probar!

Answer (score 0):

Eso puedes hacerlo simplemente con `foreach`, recorre el `data` con ello, tomand tu ejemplo:

```
$championData = json_decode(file_get_contents("./media/other/champion.json"))['data'];

foreach ($championData as $data) {
  if ($data['key'] == '233') {
    print_r($data['id']);
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Cierto, gracias, ahora bien si encuentro lo necesitado con un break; deberia bastar para no seguir recorriendo el foreach cierto?

Comment: @JorgeMontejo si quieres, ese break lo puedes poner terminando la condicion (dentro de las llaves), edite mi pregunta para que veas

Comment: Si no le indicas a json_decode que debe devolver un array asociativo, tengo entendido que devuelve un objeto, con lo cual `$data['key']` es incorrecto y dará error `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array` en algunas versiones de PHP

Comment: @Benito-B cierto, he mandado solicidtud de edicion para esa parte!

Comment: La otra opción, tal como indico en mi respuesta, es no usar un array asociativo y acceder al objeto directamente. Te evitas los corchetes y las comillas en cada acceso, con lo cual es más fácil y rápido de escribir. Aparte de la facilidad de escribir, ambos métodos son exactamente igual de válidos :)