# ¿Cómo seleccionar datos de un json en php?

Tags: php, json, api, rest

Amigos,

Me encuentro trabajando con una api rest que me devuelve en json los datos, y lo que quiero es coger siempre el ultimo dato añadido que en este caso seria el [0]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el php curl seria el siguiente:

```
$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

echo $response;
$response = json_decode($response); 
//echo $response->msg;
if ($response->msg == "User added!") {

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://gateway.cloud/app-api.php?api-id=cokdgqtb0etss8krks42fd70em&get-contacts=",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Cookie: PHPSESSID=cokdgqtb0etss8krks42fd70em'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

echo $response;
```

Como podria seleccionar los datos marcados en la imagen?

Comment: Cuando usas json_decode, este transforma el json a un array que entienda php. Entonces, entendiendo un poco tu json, supongo que sería algo como: `$response['data'][0]['id'];`

Comment: segun el ajax que hayas usado... el cual no haz puesto, puedes seleccionar todos los elementos del json con `$_POST` o `$_GET` dependiendo de como hagas los request

Comment: Creo que hace hace la petición con curl @EgonStetmann.

Comment: solicito la informacion a una api de un servicio externo, entonces consulto por curl y ahi el response no me reconoce esa funcion `$response['data'][0]['id'];`

Comment: esta es la respuesta al usar esa funcion

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\sms\send.php:52 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\sms\send.php on line 52`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero decodifica el json para facilitar la manipulación:

```
$json = json_decode($response);
```

El primer contacto lo obtienes con: `$id = $json->data[0]->id;`

Si necesitas recorrer cada contacto:

```
foreach( $json->data as $i => $contacto ){
    echo $i.': '.$contacto->id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yo no sé si nos estamos perdiendo algo pero creo que la respuesta de @gaidyjg era correcta. No puedes acceder a los indices porque no estás trabajando sobre un array sino sobre un objeto Json. Solo tienes que utilizar el Json_decode para convertirlo en un array y así acceder a los índices.
Ej: $data = json_decode($response);
$member_id = $data['data'][0]['id'];
El usuario @Benito-b lo explica bien en [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/414826/acceder-a-json-por-indice-en-php).